# Less rows than expected after comparing two files

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two files to be compared:

1. "base" file from where I get values in the second column after comparing it with "temp" file
2. "temp" file which is continuously changing (e.g., in every loop)

"base" file:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
7 g
8 h
9 i
```

"temp" file:

```
2.3
1.8
4.5
```

For comparison, the following code is used:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;next} {i=int($1+.01)} i in A {print A[i]}' base temp
```

Therefore, it outputs:

```
b
a
d
```

As noticed, even though there are decimals numbers in "temp" file, the corresponding letters are found and printed. However, I found that with a larger file (e.g., more than a couple of thousands row records in "temp" file) the code always outputs "158" rows less than the actual number of rows in the "temp" file. I do not get why this happens and would like your support to circumvent this.

In the following example, "tmpctd" is the base file and "tmpsf" is the changing file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;next} {i=int($1+.01)} i in A {print A[i]}' tmpctd tmpsf
```

The above comparison produces 22623 rows, but the "tmpsf" (i.e., "temp" file) has 22781 rows. Thus, 158 rows less after comparing both files. For testing please find these files here: https://file.io/pxi24ZtPt0kD and https://file.io/tHgdI3dkbKhr.

Any hints are welcomed.

PS. I updated both links, sorry for that.

Comment: Try  `awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;next} {i=int($1+.01)} !(i in A){print $0}' base temp`, it will print the cases for which nothing matched, could be numbers not in `base` or just not numbers, for which `int()` evaluated to zero. It should be 158 lines.

Comment: @JamesBrown please find the updated links, it seems that "Ephmeral file sharing" web site (https://www.file.io/) is very ephemeral.

Comment: @thanasisp nice trick, I found those that are not in the base file, thanks for that!, you were totally right, 158 rows.

Comment: good news. Have a nice day.

Comment: Don't post links (or images). Post concise, testable textual sample input/output that reproduce your problem in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[int($1)]
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print $2
}
' temp_file base_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                   ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when temp_file is being read.
  a[int($1)]               ##Creating array a which has index as integer value of 1st field of current line.
  next                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in a){                 ##Checking condition if first field is present in array a then do following.
  print $2                 ##Printing 2nd field of currnet line.
}
' temp_file base_file      ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```