# Comparing two large files in bash and looking for performance

Tags: linux, bash, performance, csv, awk

I've been scratching my head for a while about this problem. I have two files:

`base.csv`

```
6517.49,450.0N,450.0N,-79.5664,-7.9726,280.434,-7.9726
6542.77,300.0N,300.0N,-79.5376,-8.0679,280.462,-8.0679
6530.41,300.0N,300.0N,-79.6216,-7.9845,280.378,-7.9845
```

`tocompare.csv`

```
7233.28,-81.59,-5.13513513514,278.41,-5.13513513514
7224.23,-81.59,-5.1951951952,278.41,-5.1951951952
```

and with the percentage difference below 10.5% between the 1st column value of both files (eg. 1st row -> `7233.28` in `tocompare.csv` vs `6517.49` in `base.csv`), I need to output columns of both files. To get the percentage difference I use `awk` (I use the following values as example because they only satisfy the condition of <10.5% difference between both values):

```
$ echo 6542.77 7224.23 | awk 'function abs(x){ return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x) } { print (abs($1-$2)/$1)*100"%" }'
10.4155%
```

Thus, in the first comparison run I want `7233.28` (`tocompare.csv`) to be compared with all values of the 1st column in `base.csv`. So, `7233.28` is 3 times compared against 1st column `base.csv`. Then, the process starts again with `7224.23` and so on.

Below is the result of the 1st and 2nd runs, where the 1st run prints nothing and only one outcome appears after the 2nd run (ie. `6542.77` vs `7224.23`):

```
2nd column base.csv   2nd column tocompare.csv   3rd column tocompare.csv
300.0N                -81.59                     -5.1951951952
```

My doubt is performance because the original files are quite large. For instance, based on these two CSV files there will be 6 row comparisons (`base.csv` has 3 rows, `tocompare.csv` has 2 rows). The original files have 300 rows and 20 000 rows, respectively (so, 6 million comparisons). However, I expect that nothing gets printed as the condition is not satisfied, which supports the timing and perfomance of the calculations.

So, is the nice `awk` the right tool for this task? if so, how can I compare these two files to get the expected output file?

Any hints will be much appreciated,

Comment: There is a chance that a compiled program performs better, especially if you can read the entire files into large arrays  (which should not be a problem for such small-ish files) and perform the computations without touching the files again.

Comment: awk if very fast. Based on your description, I would look to either Ruby or Python with Pandas. Both of those are easier to manipulate tables.

Comment: Confused however: For the first row of `base.csv` with the value of `6517.49` you would comapre that with each line of `tocompare.csv`? Then the second line of `base.csv` with `6519.47` is then compared to each line of `tocompare.csv` and so on?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! sorry if I wasn't clear @dawg, indeed I want `7233.28` (tocompare.csv) to be compared with that 1st column of `base.csv` (first row `6517.49`). So, `7233.28` is the first run (ie. 10 times compared against 1st column `base.csv`) and then comes `7224.23` and so on. If `7233.28` is not that different from `6517.49` (15% threshold), the 3-columns output file is expected. I just updated my post with this description. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Gery: Please update your intended output for the entire lines of the input. If that is too long, shorten the input. Only 1 line example is too ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks again for all the support, please find my updates above to further clarify my post.

Comment: also, please update the question with your complete set of code, eg, the additional code that is comparing the `abs()` result to generate the desired output

Comment: are you by any chance trying to use the `awk / abs()` output to perform comparisons in `bash`? if the answer is 'yes' then, yeah, you're going to have performance issues trying to use (a pair of nested loops in) `bash` to perform the comparisons; you'd be better off performing the entire operation (division, abs(), comparison, print output) in a single `awk` script

Comment: so far no code, just keep testing, that's why I'm still scratching my head... hope someone else could provide further hints.

Comment: Question: *I want 7233.28 (tocompare.csv) to be compared with the 1st column of base.csv* What does that mean to compare a **single value** to a **column of values**? Does that mean ANY value in the 1st column with the 10.5% difference or all of them or some other formulae? Or does it mean compare one by one?

Comment: The first step is writing a program is to get a very concise description. You don't have that yet...

Comment: If your primary goal is performance, you should really be using an indexed datastore for this -- something like SQLite -- rather than operating on CSV files at all. (Even if your data all fits in memory, SQLite can _still_ be faster, because indexes can be used to isolate only the data that can possibly be involved in a join and avoid even needing to consider the rest at all).

Comment: (BTW, while the consensus close reason was "needs details or clarity", my vote was for "too broad"; there's no single narrow, specific technical issue this question focuses on, reducing the chances that someone else with the same problem will be able to find and learn from its answers: the overwhelming of people with a bash script comparing two files that's too slow will have one too slow for different/unrelated reasons, with no good way to filter search results to find this question and its answers).

Comment: (...in particular, the _most common_ case where bash comparisons are too slow are places where people use `diff` but instead should be using `comm`, or are accepting unsorted inputs but need to use sorted inputs to allow use of tools like `join`; you've got a weird case, but haven't isolated the things that _make_ it weird and are thus instead asking for broader guidance without writing a title and description that make the question and its answers easy to find for people who are stuck on the same corner cases).

Comment: What version of `awk` are you using (use `awk --version` to find that)?

Comment: @Daweo, ...mind, if `--version` works, that _itself_ narrows down which version the OP can have (`--long`-form option names being a GNUism that baseline-POSIX tools aren't required to support)

Comment: @Daweo `GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)`, thanks for asking! and thanks also @Charles Duffy for the comments here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions/understandings:

- we want to find the 'percentage difference' of the cartesian product of the two files (ie, all 1st columns from `base.csv` + all 1st columns from `tocompare.csv`)
- only generate the 3-column output when the 'percentage difference' is < 10.5

One `awk` idea:

```
$ cat abs.awk

function abs(x) { return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x) }

BEGIN   { FS = "," }

FNR==NR { col1[++cnt] = $1                                       # 1st file: save column 1
          col2[  cnt] = $2                                       # save column 2
          next
        }
        { for (i=1; i<=cnt; i++)                                 # 2nd file: loop through list of 1st columns from 1st file
              if (abs(col1[i]-$1)/col1[i] * 100 < 10.5)          # if calculation is less than 10.5 then ...
                 print col2[i], $2, $3                           # print 3-column output
        }
```

This generates:

```
$ awk -f abs.awk base.csv tocompare.csv
300.0N -81.59 -5.1951951952
```

---

Taking a look at performance ...

OP has mentioned the real files are 300 lines (`base.csv`) and 20,000 lines (`tocompare.csv`).  I duplicated the lines in both files to get up to the desired row counts:

```
$ wc -l base.300.csv tocompare.20K.csv
    300 base.300.csv
  20000 tocompare.20K.csv
```

Timing the `awk` script against the larger files:

```
$ time awk -f abs.awk base.300.csv tocompare.20K.csv > x

real    0m1.127s
user    0m1.094s
sys     0m0.032s
```

**NOTES:**

- `i7-1260P` running `Ubuntu 22.04` and `GNU awk 5.1.0`
- ~1.2 seconds to perform the 6 million `abs() / comparison` operations
- in previous edits of the question OP mentioned 'getting rid of values' and 'skipping calculations' but we're given no details on what this means; if OP has additional logic that would allow us to reduce the number of `abs() / comparison` operations then it may be possible to reduce the run time below the current ~1.2 seconds

Verifying we get the same result:

```
$ sort -u x
300.0N -81.59 -5.1951951952
```

Comment: Wow! thanks for the neat answers @markp-fuso and @dawg, I will stick to the `awk` solution here, I was testing some previous awk calls with arrays and some other variations like in my old posts (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975887/less-rows-than-expected-after-comparing-two-files/63976154#63976154) but your solution is much nicer @markp-fuso and with new tricks for me (eg. cnt), so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
head *.csv
==> base.csv <==
6517.49,450.0N,450.0N,-79.5664,-7.9726,280.434,-7.9726
6542.77,300.0N,300.0N,-79.5376,-8.0679,280.462,-8.0679
6530.41,300.0N,300.0N,-79.6216,-7.9845,280.378,-7.9845

==> tocompare.csv <==
7233.28,-81.59,-5.13513513514,278.41,-5.13513513514
7224.23,-81.59,-5.1951951952,278.41,-5.1951951952
```

The closest I can come to a next step for you is this Ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'BEGIN{opts={:converters => :numeric} }
base,tc=[0,1].map{|fn| CSV.parse(File.open(ARGV[fn]).read, **opts)}
idx={}
tc.each.with_index{|tc_row, i| 
    base.each.with_index{|base_row,j| idx[i]=j if (base_row[0]-tc_row[0]).abs/base_row[0]<0.105} 
}
idx.each{|k,v| puts "#{base[k][1]}\t#{tc[v][1]}\t#{tc[v][2]}" }

' base.csv tocompare.csv
```

Prints:

```
300.0N  -81.59  -5.1951951952
```